# Idiomatic way to move values from vector to predefined slice?

Tags: rust

I am playing audio file with `cpal` lib here. Of course I can do it using loops, but this is not idiomatic enough! I believe there should be an elegant function with a small name somewhere in `std` which performs exactly this, but I failed to find it.

```rust
  let pcm = read_file("audio.f32le").unwrap();
  let mut j = 0;

  let stream = output_dev
    .build_output_stream(
      &output_conf,
      move |data: &mut [f32], _: &cpal::OutputCallbackInfo| {
        let mut i = 0;
        let l = data.len();
        while i < l {
          data[i] = pcm[j];
          i = i + 1;
          j = j + 1;
        }
      },
      move |err| panic!("Stream error, {:?}", err),
    )
    .unwrap();
  stream.play().unwrap();
  thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(20 + 4 * 60));
```

Comment: What's wrong with [`copy_from_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice)?

Comment: It is better than just loop but I still have to keep vector index

Comment: I would first not read all my file... this defeat all the purpose of chunk the output.